# PHPUnit Mocking methods calls in a mocked method

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to write a basic unit test to see if a method is called in another method.

I have a class like the following:

```
class Hello
{
    public function doSomething($something)
    {
        if ($something == 1) {
            return $this->methodA();
        } else {
            return $this->methodB();
        }
    }

    protected function methodA() : bool
    {
        // code here
    }


    protected function methodB(): bool
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Both `methodA()` and `methodB()` return a boolean, which is fine, I don’t want to test the return value.

What I want to do though is mock class, call `doSomething()` method and check which method is returned, either `methodA()` or `methodB()`.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since this appear to be a functionality that you test and it is embedded into a function, it means that your method is not atomic. A solution to this problem would be to make it atomic:

```
class Hello
{

    protected function isA($something)
    {
        return ($something = 1); //Did you mean $something == 1?
    }

    public function doSomething($something)
    {
        if ($this->isA($something)) {
            return $this->methodA();
        } else {
            return $this->methodB();
        }
    }

    protected function methodA() : bool
    {
        // code here
    }


    protected function methodB(): bool
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

and then you can test `isA` as you please. I'm not sure whether you really wanted to assign 1 to `$something` or that was just a typo, so added a comment there and fixed some other typos that you had.